# How transfer learning on EfficientNets work for grayscale images?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, transfer-learning

My question concerns more about how the algorithm work. I have successfully implemented EfficientNet integration and modelization for grayscale images and now I want to understand why it works.

Here the most important aspect is the grayscale and its 1 channel. When I put `channels=1`, the algorithm doesn't work because, if I understood right, it was made on 3-channel images. When I put `channels=3` it works perfectly.

So my question is, when I put `channels = 3` and feed the model with preprocessed images with `channels=1`, why it continues to work?

Code for EfficientNetB5

```
# Variable assignments
num_classes = 9
img_height = 84
img_width = 112
channels = 3
batch_size = 32

# Make the input layer
new_input = Input(shape=(img_height, img_width, channels),
                  name='image_input')

# Download and use EfficientNetB5
tmp = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB5(include_top=False,
                                           weights='imagenet',
                                           input_tensor=new_input,
                                           pooling='max')
model = Sequential()
model.add(tmp)  # adding EfficientNetB5
model.add(Flatten())
...
```

Code of preprocessing into grayscale

```
data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(
        validation_split=0.2)

train_generator = data_generator.flow_from_directory(
        train_path,
        target_size=(img_height, img_width),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode="grayscale", ###################################
        class_mode="categorical",
        subset="training")
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I was wondering the same thing.  I get a warning about input shape because i only have 1 channel (greyscale images) not 3 , but it still trains the model.

Comment: @erotavlas noo, I posted this question in other places, but no one answered it :/

Comment: @erotavlas please check the answers, I got an excellent answer by afm215.. already a year passed but anyway wanted to point it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dug into what happens when you give grayscale images to efficient net models with three-channel inputs.
Here are the first layers of Efficient Net B5 whose input_shape is (128,128,3)

```
 Layer (type)                   Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
 input_7 (InputLayer)           [(None, 128, 128, 3  0           []                               
                                )]                                                                
                                                                                                  
 rescaling_7 (Rescaling)        (None, 128, 128, 3)  0           ['input_7[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 normalization_13 (Normalizatio  (None, 128, 128, 3)  7          ['rescaling_7[0][0]']            
 n)                                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.truediv_4 (TFOpLambda)  (None, 128, 128, 3)  0          ['normalization_13[0][0]']       
                                                                                                  
 stem_conv_pad (ZeroPadding2D)  (None, 129, 129, 3)  0           ['tf.math.truediv_4[0][0]']
```

And here is the shape of the output of each of these layers when the model has as input a grayscale image:

```
input_7 (128, 128, 1)
rescaling_7 (128, 128, 1)
normalization_13 (128, 128, 3)
tf.math.truediv_4 (128, 128, 3)
stem_conv_pad (129, 129, 3)
```

As you can see, the number of channels of the output tensor switches from 1 to 3 when proceeding to the normalization_13 layer, so let's see what this layer is actually doing.
The Normalization layer is performing this operation on the input tensor:

```
(input_tensor - self.mean) / sqrt(self.var) // see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Normalization
```

The number of channels changes after the subtraction. As a matter of fact, self.mean looks like this :

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1, 1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[[[0.485, 0.456, 0.406]]]], dtype=float32)>
```

So self.mean has three channels and when performing the subtraction between a tensor with one channel and a tensor with three channels, the output looks like this: `[firstTensor - secondTensorFirstChannel, firstTensor - secondTensorSecondChannel, firstTensor - secondTensorThirdChannel]`
And this is how the magic happens and this is why the model can take as input grayscale images!
I have checked this with efficient net B5 and with efficient net B2V2. Even if they have differences in the way the Normalization layer is declared, the process is the same. I suppose that is also the case for the other efficient net models.

I hope it was clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting. If training still works with `channels = 3` even though the input is grayscale, I would check the batch shape of the `train_generator`(maybe print a couple of batches to get a feel for it). Here is a code snippet to quickly check the batch shape. (plotImages() is available in Tensorflow docs)

```
imgs,labels = next(train_generator)
print('Batch shape: ',imgs.shape)
plotImages(imgs,labels)
```